# Enforce User Mode in Dynamic SOQL - String or Parameter?

Tags: apex, soql, security, user-mode

Is it equally appropriate and safe to use each of those Dynamic SOQL calls with USER MODE or should I prepare one over the other? The [official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_enforce_usermode.htm) doesn't make that clear.

**User Mode as part of the Query String**

```
Database.query('SELECT ... WITH USER_MODE');
```

**User Mode as Parameter**

```
Database.query('SELECT ...', AccessLevel.USER_MODE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation doesn't make a distinction because there is no technical distinction. The main benefit of using the `AccessLevel` is that it helps avoid false positives when you're using the automated security scanning tools that you'd use to pass a Security Review.